# React with Typescript how to customize primary color as my own color of palette object and how to use them in typescript of Functional components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHubR.jpg)

React with Typescript how to customize primary color as my own color of palette object and how to use them in typescript of Functional components and with react 18 version and MUI latest version using as 5.15

Comment: step1: created a module augmentation declaration 
declare module "@mui/material/styles/createPalette" {
  interface PaletteOptions {

    appcolor?: PaletteColorOptions;
  }
  interface Palette {

    appcolor: PaletteColor;
  }
}

declare module "@mui/material" {

  interface LinerProgressPropsColorOverrides {

    appcolor: true;
  }
}

Comment: step2: create a theme 

const themeOptions: ThemeOptions = {

  palette: {

    appcolor: {

      contrastText: "#222",

      dark: "#1565c0",
      light: "#42a5f5",
      main: "#1976d2"
    }
  }
};

Comment: step3: globally override the theme component and passing custom them 

const theme = createTheme({
     ...theme,
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiLinerProgress: {
      defaultProps: {
        // The props to change the default for.
       
      },
    },
  },
});

Comment: setp4: passed theme to themprovider import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import CustomButton from "./CustomButton";
import theme from "./theme";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <app/>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

Comment: step5 : now under the root app component using a  LinerProgress component in typescript where i want to pass default color property value of my custom color instead of primary value as follows
<CircularProgress color="appcolor" /> -- here i want pass appcolor ,now how to achieve the by using typescript ?



<CircularProgress color="appcolor" /> -- here i want pass as custom palette appcolor ,now how to achieve the by using typescript ?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).